# How does printing Josephus sequence work?

Tags: c++, algorithm, josephus

The CSES problem Josephus Problem I requires us to print the sequence of how people are chosen for n people and k = 2. I found an elegant solution to this [here](https://github.com/mrsac7/CSES-Solutions/blob/master/src/2162%20-%20Josephus%20Problem%20I.cpp).
Basically, the code is similar to this:

```
void J(int n)
{
    int a = 1, b = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i += 2)
        {
            cout << a * i + b << ' ';
        }
        if (n & 1)
            cout << a + b << ' ', b += a;
        else
            b -= a;
        a <<= 1;
        n >>= 1;
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why it works?

Comment: Please focus on one question only. And try to make it more specific. Did you implement it and step through the code with a debugger to inspect the progress?

Comment: Yes i did. The issue isn't that I don't know how the values some values are printing or not. I am not able to understand the algorithm used. Because of this, dry running or debugging this isn't really helping

Comment: There are multiple questions (explain how, explain why, what time complexity, how to generlize, ...?). Focus on one only.

Comment: Ok. Currently, I am just focusing on trying to understand the approach

Comment: So, can you edit your question accordingly? And could you make it more specific as to which part is what you don't understand?

Comment: OK. I have edited the question

Comment: This is a coincidence) The same [question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1312186/Как-работает-данный-код-с) was asked on ruSO (russian SO). There is a small explanation, but it is not complete. I also found another [solution](https://cses.fi/paste/ee6f9c823d514403279c6a/) to this problem on cses. Pretty self-explanatory, but I personally don't understand how it works (

Answer (score 2):

I made a few changes to the code to illustrate how it works.

```
void J(int n)
{
    int a = 1, b = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        std::cout << "n=" << n << std::endl;
        std::cout << "a=" << a << ", b=" << b << std::endl;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i += 2)
        {
            std::cout << a * i + b << ' ';
        }

        if (n & 1) // equivalent to n % 2 == 1 (if n is odd)
            std::cout << '*' << a + b << ' ', b += a;
        else
            b -= a;
        
        std::cout << std::endl;
        a <<= 1; // a = a * 2;
        n >>= 1; // n = n / 2;
    }
}
```

The first thing to note is that the variables `a` and `b` are initialized to values that allow us to compute the positions of people who will be eliminated as we go around the circle (also using the iterator `i` in the `for` loop). The initial values of `a = 1, b = 0` are so we can eliminate every even numbered person on the first iteration.

Next, every time through the `while(n)` loop, half of the remaining people will be eliminated. If `n` is odd, we loop back to the beginning of the circle and also eliminate the person at the start of the current iteration.

I think the tricky part here is how the values of `a` and `b` change in the `if` statement. If `n` is odd we increment `b` by the value of `a`. If `n` is even we subtract the value of `a` from `b`. Then we double the value of `a` to get ready for the next iteration around the circle. The values of `a` and `b` are chosen to account for the gaps in the circle left by eliminating positions in the previous iterations.

Finally, we divide `n` by 2 before the next iteration, since there are half as many people left in the circle. Here's a sample run for `n=19`.

Output:

```
n=19
a=1, b=0
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 *1
n=9
a=2, b=1
5 9 13 17 *3
n=4
a=4, b=3
11 19
n=2
a=8, b=-1
15
n=1
a=16, b=-9
*7
```